# How to know CouchDB has changed in IONIC app?

Tags: mobile, ionic-framework, synchronization, couchdb, pouchdb

I am developing an Appointment App using Ionic framework with **PouchDB** & **CouchDB**.

Changes made in the App are saved in PouchDB and local database perfectly syncs/saves data to the Couch database - instantly.

But how do I know when the CouchDB has been changed ?

I am syncing two databases in the `.run()` function - but `.run()` is only invoked when the app starts.

How do I know there is a change in the remote database when the app is running / being used?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of PouchDB replicate/sync is a [event emitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter). To listen for server changes you should replicate/sync remote DB using `{live: true}` and register your handlers.
For example:

```
localDB.sync(remoteDB, {
  live: true,
  retry: true
}).on('change', function (change) {
  // notify to your app that the remote Couch DB has changed
}).on('paused', function (info) {
  // replication was paused, usually because of a lost connection
}).on('active', function (info) {
  // replication was resumed
}).on('error', function (err) {
  // totally unhandled error (shouldn't happen)
})));
```

More details on [pouchdb documentation](http://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html#live%E2%80%93replication).

Comment: Hi Federico, Thank you so much for the insight. I will test the solution and will get back to you with results. Thanks a ton.